# OpenStack Ansible deployment fails due to lxc containers not having network connection

Tags: ubuntu, openstack, lxc

I'm trying to deploy OpenStack Ansible. When running the first playbook `openstack-ansible setup-hosts.yml`, there are errors for all containers during the task `[openstack_hosts : Remove the blacklisted packages]` (see below) and the playbook fails.

```
fatal: [infra1_repo_container-1f1565cd]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "apt-get update", "msg": "E: The repository 'http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu bionic Release' no longer has a Release file.\nE: The repository 'http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu bionic-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.\nE: The repository 'http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu bionic-backports Release' no longer has a Release file.\nE: The repository 'http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu bionic-security Release' no longer has a Release file.", "rc": 100, "stderr": "E: The repository 'http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu bionic Release' no longer has a Release file.\nE: The repository 'http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu bionic-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.\nE: The repository 'http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu bionic-backports Release' no longer has a Release file.\nE: The repository 'http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu bionic-security Release' no longer has a Release file.\n", "stderr_lines": ["E: The repository 'http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu bionic Release' no longer has a Release file.", "E: The repository 'http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu bionic-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.", "E: The repository 'http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu bionic-backports Release' no longer has a Release file.", "E: The repository 'http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu bionic-security Release' no longer has a Release file."], "stdout": "Ign:1 http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu bionic InRelease\nIgn:2 http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease\nIgn:3 http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease\nIgn:4 http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease\nErr:5 http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu bionic Release\n  Cannot initiate the connection to 192.168.100.6:8000 (192.168.100.6). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)\nErr:6 http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu bionic-updates Release\n  Cannot initiate the connection to 192.168.100.6:8000 (192.168.100.6). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)\nErr:7 http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu bionic-backports Release\n  Cannot initiate the connection to 192.168.100.6:8000 (192.168.100.6). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)\nErr:8 http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu bionic-security Release\n  Cannot initiate the connection to 192.168.100.6:8000 (192.168.100.6). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)\nReading package lists...\n", "stdout_lines": ["Ign:1 http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu bionic InRelease", "Ign:2 http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease", "Ign:3 http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease", "Ign:4 http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease", "Err:5 http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu bionic Release", "  Cannot initiate the connection to 192.168.100.6:8000 (192.168.100.6). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)", "Err:6 http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu bionic-updates Release", "  Cannot initiate the connection to 192.168.100.6:8000 (192.168.100.6). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)", "Err:7 http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu bionic-backports Release", "  Cannot initiate the connection to 192.168.100.6:8000 (192.168.100.6). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)", "Err:8 http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu bionic-security Release", "  Cannot initiate the connection to 192.168.100.6:8000 (192.168.100.6). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)", "Reading package lists..."]}
```

When I attach to any container and run `ping 192.168.100.6` (local DNS), I get the same error (`connect: Network is unreachable`). However, when I specify an interface by running `ping -I eth1 192.168.100.6` there is a successful connection.
Running `ip r` on the infra_cinder container yields:

```
10.0.3.0/24 dev eth2 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.3.5 
192.168.110.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.110.232
```

so there seems to be no default route which is why the connection fails (similar for the other infra containers). Shouldn't OSA automatically configure this? I didn't find anything regarding a default route on containers in the Docs.

Here's my openstack_user_config.yml:

```
cidr_networks:
  container: 192.168.110.0/24
  tunnel: 192.168.32.0/24
  storage: 10.0.3.0/24

used_ips:
  - "192.168.110.1,192.168.110.2" 
  - "192.168.110.111" 
  - "192.168.110.115" 
  - "192.168.110.117,192.168.110.118" 
  - "192.168.110.131,192.168.110.140" 
  - "192.168.110.201,192.168.110.207" 
  - "192.168.32.1,192.168.32.2" 
  - "192.168.32.201,192.168.32.207" 
  - "10.0.3.1" 
  - "10.0.3.11,10.0.3.14" 
  - "10.0.3.21,10.0.3.24" 
  - "10.0.3.31,10.0.3.42" 
  - "10.0.3.201,10.0.3.207" 

global_overrides:
  # The internal and external VIP should be different IPs, however they
  # do not need to be on separate networks.
  external_lb_vip_address: 192.168.100.168
  internal_lb_vip_address: 192.168.110.201
  management_bridge: "br-mgmt" 
  provider_networks:
    - network:
        container_bridge: "br-mgmt" 
        container_type: "veth" 
        container_interface: "eth1" 
        ip_from_q: "container" 
        type: "raw" 
        group_binds:
          - all_containers
          - hosts
        is_container_address: true
    - network:
        container_bridge: "br-vxlan" 
        container_type: "veth" 
        container_interface: "eth10" 
        ip_from_q: "tunnel" 
        type: "vxlan" 
        range: "1:1000" 
        net_name: "vxlan" 
        group_binds:
          - neutron_linuxbridge_agent
    - network:
        container_bridge: "br-ext1" 
        container_type: "veth" 
        container_interface: "eth12" 
        host_bind_override: "eth12" 
        type: "flat" 
        net_name: "ext_net" 
        group_binds:
          - neutron_linuxbridge_agent
    - network:
        container_bridge: "br-storage" 
        container_type: "veth" 
        container_interface: "eth2" 
        ip_from_q: "storage" 
        type: "raw" 
        group_binds:
          - glance_api
          - cinder_api
          - cinder_volume
          - nova_compute
          - swift-proxy

###
### Infrastructure
###

# galera, memcache, rabbitmq, utility
shared-infra_hosts:
  infra1:
    ip: 192.168.110.201

# repository (apt cache, python packages, etc)
repo-infra_hosts:
  infra1:
    ip: 192.168.110.201

# load balancer
haproxy_hosts:
  infra1:
    ip: 192.168.110.201

###
### OpenStack
###

os-infra_hosts:
   infra1:
     ip: 192.168.110.201

identity_hosts:
   infra1:
     ip: 192.168.110.201

network_hosts:
   infra1:
     ip: 192.168.110.201

compute_hosts:
   compute1:
     ip: 192.168.110.204
   compute2:
     ip: 192.168.110.205
   compute3:
     ip: 192.168.110.206
   compute4:
     ip: 192.168.110.207

storage-infra_hosts:
   infra1:
     ip: 192.168.110.201

storage_hosts:
   lvm-storage1:
     ip: 192.168.110.202
     container_vars:
       cinder_backends:
         lvm:
           volume_backend_name: LVM_iSCSI
           volume_driver: cinder.volume.drivers.lvm.LVMVolumeDriver
           volume_group: cinder_volumes
           iscsi_ip_address: "{{ cinder_storage_address }}" 
         limit_container_types: cinder_volume
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to backtrack from my configuration to the AIO but the same error kept showing up. Finally it disappeared after rebooting the servers so there didn't seem to be a problem with the configuration after all...